# How to Find References of a Method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have below method In my project and I'm not able to find the references of it by press Shift+F12 (or select Find All References), How can I find the all references of method like below?

```
public override string[] Convert(object input)
{
}
```

Update : The above method is under this class:

```
public class AutoClerkReservationMessageToPMSConverter : BaseAutoClerkMessageConverter
{
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2013,and by pressing Shift+F12 (or select Find All References) I'm getting below references, which are actually not the references?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you click Find All References ? Which version of VS you're using ? Probably the method is not used anywhere ?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev: Please check update.

Comment: are you sure that the method is actually used? :)

Comment: @DimitarTsonev: yes it is, as per the working of application :)

Comment: Perhaps view call hierarchy is what you are after if you want to see all the places this method is being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must select class, method, varible ets... if you have ReSharper press ctrl + mouse left button click. if you have not ReSharper then press only F12

Comment: don't those hotkeys *"go to the definition"*?

Comment: yes those hotkeys is "go to definition"`s shortcuts.  you`re look all referance or find press ctrl+alt+j or view=>object browser

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `BaseAutoClerkMessageConverter` inherit from `BaseMessageConverter` which extends `IMessageConverter`.

So my advice would be to press Shift+F12 from `IMessageConverter.Convert`.

PS : Use Resharper if possible.